# How to run an OpenShift JBoss AS 7 app on localhost through Eclipse(Kepler)?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, openshift

I tried to run an OpenShift JBoss AS 7 app through Eclipse as a normal JBoss AS 7 App but it doesn't seem to work. I have the OpenShift JBoss Tools installed in eclipse. 
However when I try to run it through Run As --> Run on Server and then selecting the "jboss-as-7.0.1.Final Runtime Server" listed in the "Servers" view, I get the error

```
"the selection does not contain any resources that can run on a server".
```

To solve this I changed the project facet to Dynamic Web Module, then I again tried running it on JBoss server, but the application doesn't deploy and I get a 404 error on accessing its localhost url.

I also noticed that the JBoss Server's status in my eclipse "Servers" view is always shown as "Starting"(doesn't change to "Started"), although the Console shows something like "JBoss AS 7.0.1.Final "Zap" started in 2236ms"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://www.openshift.com/blogs/day-28-openshift-eclipse-integration-for-java-developers. That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However it seems that this tutorial is for deployment on OpenShift server. I wanted to run the application on localhost JBoss server for faster debugging and other features.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing right now, what you want to do. I have a Project which is deployable on OpenShift and on my local installation of the jboss 7.1.

It is very strange that eclipse shows your jboss as always starting. I would recommend to delete the server in eclipse and try to add it again. Also you can add the project in the servers view. For that you right click your server and choose "Add and Remove...". You can choose the Project, add it to the server and eclipse is deploying it.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of JBoss Tools are you running ? There have been some issues with detection of the server running in past where you can workaround this issue of the server not launching by changing the "Startup poller" to "web poller" or "timeout poller".

btw. if you needed to change your project to be a dynamic web project that indicates to me you have not actually imported the project as a maven project and had all of JBoss Tools installed (or at least M2e-wtp) which would normtally automatically make the import of the default openshift apps into a dynamic web project.